# Which relay objects must implement `Node`?

Tags: relayjs

https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/objectidentification.htm is very clear around what `Node` is and how it behaves, but it doesn't specify which objects must implement it, or what the consequences are if your object doesn't implement it. Is there a set of features that don't work? Are such objects completely ignored? Not all objects in the existing spec (e.g. `pageInfo`) implement it, so it's clearly not universally required, but `pageInfo` is somewhat of a special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way of thinking about the `Node` interface is that objects that implement it are *refetchable*. Refetchability effectively means that an object has an ID that I can use to identify the object and retrieve it; by convention, these IDs will usually be opaque, but will contain type information and an identifier within that type (eg. a Base-64 encoding of a string like "Account:1234").

Relay will leverage refetchability in two ways:

- Under a process known as "diffing", if you already have some data for an object identified by ID `QWNjb3VudDoxMjM0` (say, the `name` and `address` fields), and you then navigate to a view where we show some additional fields (`location`, `createdAt`) then Relay can make a minimal query that "refetches" the node but only requests the missing fields.
- Relatedly, Relay will diff connections and will make use of the `Node` interface to fill in missing data on those (example: through some combination of navigation you might have full information for some items in a view, but need to fill in `location` for some items within the range, or you might modify an item in a connection via a mutation). So, in basic pagination, Relay will often end up making a `first` + `after` query to extend a connection, but if you inspect its network traffic in a real app you will also see that it makes `node` queries for items within connections.

So yes, you're right that `pageInfo` doesn't implement `Node`, and it wouldn't really make sense for it to do so.

Comment: Which is to say: nothing *needs* to implement `Node`, but objects that do will be handled more efficiently? I now see that https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm mentions "Relay can perform certain optimizations if this field returns an object that implements Node, however, this is not a strict requirement for use of Relay."

Comment: Correct. I don't want to be too prescriptive about this, but a good rule of thumb would probably be to implement it for the "core" objects in your business domain, and particularly those which can be navigated to via top-level routes, and which appear in connections. The optimal approach will vary by app of course, but if you can implement `Node` cheaply (and you often can) then you'll probably benefit from doing so for at least those cases that I mention in the rule of thumb above.