# When is node query called? Node resolver should be implemented on server?

Tags: relayjs

### Background

I read [Which relay objects must implement Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34948420/which-relay-objects-must-implement-node) page.

I could not understand about "diffing" process.

### Questions

1. Does Relay use `node` query instead of a query designated by developers?
   In other words, Relay can automatically optimize or minimize queries by using `node`?
2. If any one of GraphQL Objects implements `Node`, Is it required that schema `Query` should have `node` and GraphQL Server should have node resolver? What is happen even if there are not implemented?
3. How to demonstrate these situations? Does anyone have examples?